# Python Playsound 1.2 Error

Tags: python, playsound

```
<class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\VSC\Voice Asistent Pro\main.py", line 2
0, in <module>
    commands.get(command, Aeris().error)()
  File "e:\VSC\Voice Asistent Pro\functions.py", l
ine 80, in search_youtube
    self.speak('Що будемо шукати')
  File "e:\VSC\Voice Asistent Pro\functions.py", l
ine 59, in speak
    playsound("files/cache/main.mp3")
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Pyth
on\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", li
ne 37, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('play', alias, 'from 0 to', duratio
nInMS)
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Pyth
on\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", li
ne 22, in winCommand
    command = ' '.join(command).encode()
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance,
 bytes found
```

код :

```
import playsound
playsound.playsound('files/music.mp3')
```

Помогите
Тут ошибка playsound #pip install playsound==1.2
Даже переустановка модуля не помогла

Я даю у переменную строчное значение "files/cache/main.mp3"
И так со всеми звуками.

Comment: Еще бы немного кода, который и привел к данной ошибке.

Comment: Может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071536/typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-str-instance-bytes-found

Comment: @Евгений добавил код